# How to loop get method multiple times as per values fetching from database in Karate Framework

Tags: api, loops, iteration, karate

I need to hit sql query first and whatever account numbers I received from database, on each account number I need to hit Get method using karate framework.

**suppose sql query is -**
select account_no from account;

now I received 100 account number, and I want to hit get method for each account number using karate framework.

Comment: please read the docs, it will save you a lot of time: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-array-data-source